# Backbone view not rendering unless page refreshed

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm new to Backbone, and made a simple view that's rendering on the $('body') element.

It works fine when I load it in the browser from the address bar, but when I click a link in my view to go to it, it doesn't render.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, the problem seemed to be solved when I didn't render my view to the $('body') element.

I just removed the `el:$('body')` attribute, and it worked fine!